# Repositories and Services, MVC Model

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, service, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

So I've been learning about the Repository model, and it seems that it is expected that Repositories do not do a lot of intricate logic. However I also read that most of the business logic should not be inside of my `Controllers`. So where do I put it?

I've looked at some sample applications and it seems that they have **another** layer called `Services` that do more intricate logic for things. So how does this factor into the MVC pattern?

Do I want to build my services to access my repositories, and then my controllers to access my services? Like this?

```
interface IMembershipService
{
 bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
 MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password);
}
interface IMembershipRepository
{
 MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password);
}

class MembershipRepository : IMembershipRepository
{
 public MembershipRepository(ISession session)
 {
  **// this is where I am confused...** 
 }
}
class MembershipService : IMembershipService
{
 private readonly IMembershipRepository membershipRepository;
 public MembershipService(IMembershipRepository membershipRepository)
 {
  this.membershipRepository = membershipRepository;
 }

 public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
 {
   // validation logic
 }
 public MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password)
 {
  return membershipRepository.Create(username, password);
 }
}

class MembershipController : Controller
{
 private readonly IMembershipService membershipService;

 public MembershipController(IMembershipService membershipService)
 {
  this.membershipService = membershipService
 }
}
```

The marked part of my code is what confuses me. Everything I have read said I should be injecting my `ISession` into my repositories. This means I could not be injecting `ISession` into my services, so then how do I do Database access from my Services? I'm not understanding what the *appropriate* process is here.

When I put `ValidateUser` in my `IMembershipRepository`, I was told that was 'bad'. But the `IMembershipRepository` is where the database access resides. That's the intention, right? To keep the database access very minimal? But if I can't put other logic in them, then what is the point?

Can someone shed some light on this, and show me an example that might be more viable?

I am using `Fluent nHibernate`, `ASP.NET MVC 3.0`, and `Castle.Windsor`.

Should I instead do something like ...

```
class MembershipService
{
 private readonly IMembershipRepository membershipRepository;

 public MembershipService(ISession session)
 {
  membershipRepository = new MembershipRepository(session);
 }
}
```

And never give my Controllers direct access to the `Repositories`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Everything I have read said I should be injecting my ISession into my repositories.

That's correct. You need to inject the session into the repository constructor because this is where the data access is made.

> This means I could not be injecting ISession into my services, so then how do I do Database access from my Services?

You don't do database access in your services. The service relies on one or more repositories injected into its constructor and uses their respective methods. The service never directly queries the database.

So to recap:

- The repository contains the simple CRUD operations on your model. This is where the data access is performed. This data access doesn't necessary mean database. It will depend on the underlying storage you are using. For example you could be calling some remote services on the cloud to perform the data access.
- The service relies on one or more repositories to implement a business operation. This business operation might depend on one or more CRUD operations on the repositories. A service shouldn't even know about the existence of a database.
- The controller uses the service to invoke the business operation.
- In order to decrease the coupling between the different layers, interfaces are used to abstract the operations.

Comment: So ..should I inject `ISession` into my `Service`, and then pass it down into newly instantiated `Repository` objects inside of the service? I guess I am just lost as to how this relates to IoC. I added a bit at the bottom of my post, if you can look and tell me if I am understanding any better.

Comment: @Stacey, no, you don't inject `ISession` into the Service. You inject a repository into the service. And you inject the `ISession` into the repository. So in order to construct the controller you need a service and in order to construct a service you need a repository and in order to construct a repository you need an `ISession`. This plumbing is performed by the DI framework you are using.

Comment: And if my appended example is wrong, can you show me an example that would be more correct? I'm not understanding how to *instantiate* my repositories if I have to actually initialize them with the `new` keyword, because I thought _Dependency Injection_ was supposed to be doing this for me.

Comment: Alright, then I am a little more confused now. Can you show me an example that includes a Controller, Service, and Repository?

Comment: @Stacey, you already have it. It is exactly as you did in your code (except the last part where you try to pass an ISession to the Service).

Comment: Okay, how does this factor into performance, though? Sometimes I need more fine-tuned queries. Like, I may not want to get all of the data that the Repository returns. How do I handle situations like that?

Comment: @Stacey, you could handle situations like that be exposing the corresponding methods on your repositories that will do the job. Another possibility is to have your repository expose an `IQueryable<T>` and have the service select whatever it needs. This obviously supposes that your underlying ORM supports this interface.

Comment: Okay, pardon my impertinence, but if that's considered 'ok', then what is the real point of the service model? It seems to me like it is just adding another layer that isn't really needed.

Comment: @Stacey if in your service method you are simply going to delegate the call to the underlying repository then there is no point. But imagine the following situation: you perform bank wire transfers. A wire transfer is a business operation which consists of multiple simpler operations like validating the input, checking whether the `sender` account has the sufficient funds, debiting the `sender` account and crediting the `receiving` account. Now you expose on your service a method called `TransferFunds(Account from, Account to, double amount)`.

Comment: @Darin: that's textbook anemic domain.  just saying.

Comment: @qstarin, I agree but I think that it illustrates the idea very well that a business operation is usually composed of multiple CRUD operations and this is where a service layer is useful.

Comment: @Darin: I do not understand what you mean by 'anemic domain'. A quick search reveals this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model - It is my understanding that this is the _goal_ of separation of concerns, isn't it? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Stacey: What it gets at, is that we define a class like Membership.  Anemic is when that class is nothing (or little) more than properties. Chunks of data, pieces of state. All the logic, business or domain logic, about the Membership entity gets pushed away from it, into service classes etc.  That is the anti-pattern. That class, Membership, should **encapsulate** something.  Exposing it's state directly as properties (**especially** if they have plain setters) has no encapsulation at all.  We're just poking at our database, albeit in a type-safe way.

Comment: If your class exposes state, the manipulation of it occurs in several other places.  You've taken logic that can and should be coherent and centralized and instead spread it out throughout the application.  It adds to the complexity of changes when you have to consider how other parts of the application might be poking at those same bits of state.

Comment: @qstarin: Okay. I can concede to that logic. Can I bother you to add to the example in your reply and show me how you would invoke the `ChangePasswordCommandHandler`? I'm still really confused on how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IMembershipService
{
 bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
 MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password);
}
```

Creating a service like this an anti-pattern.

How many responsibilities does a service like this have?  How many reasons could it have to change?

Also, if you put your logic into services, you are going to end up with an anemic domain.  What you will end up with is procedural code in a Transaction Script style.  And I am not saying this is necessarily bad.

Perhaps a rich domain model is not appropriate for you, but it should be a conscious decision between the two, and this multiple responsibility service is not appropriate in either case.

This should be a **HUGE** red flag:

```
public MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password)
{
  return membershipRepository.Create(username, password);
}
```

What is the point?  Layers for the sake of layers?  The Service adds no value here, serves no purpose.

There are a lot of concepts missing.

First, consider using a Factory for creating objects:

```
public interface IMembershipFactory {
    MembershipCreateStatus Create(string username, string password);
}
```

The factory can encapsulate any logic that goes into building an instance or beginning the lifetime of an entity object.

Second, Repositories are an abstraction of a collection of objects.  Once you've used a factory to create an object, add it to the collection of objects.

```
var result = _membershipFactory.Create("user", "pw");
if (result.Failed); // do stuff
_membershipRepository.Add(status.NewMembership);  // assumes your status includes the newly created object
```

Lastly, `MyEntityService` class that contains a method for every operation that can be performed on an Entity just seems terribly offensive to my senses.

Instead, I try to be more explicit and better capture intent by modeling each operation not as a method on a single Service class, but as individual Command classes.

```
public class ChangePasswordCommand {
    public Guid MembershipId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Then, something has to actually *do* something when this command is sent, so we use handlers:

```
public interface IHandle<TMessageType> {
    void Execute(TMessageType message);
}

public class ChangePasswordCommandHandler : IHandle<ChangePasswordCommand> {

    public ChangePasswordCommandHandler(
         IMembershipRepository repo
      ) 
      {}

    public void Execute(ChangePasswordCommand command) {
      var membership = repo.Get(command.MembershipId);
      membership.ChangePassword(command.NewPassword);
    }
}
```

Commands are dispatched using a simple class that interfaces with our IoC container.

This helps avoids monolithic service classes and makes a project's structure and location of logic much clearer.

Comment: Your method of doing this is one I haven't seen before. Do you have any documentation on the way you're going about this? Like how you would wire this up in the IoC container?

Comment: an end to end example involves a lot of little pieces - it's probably why we don't see many quality samples out there, but instead see the over simplified (and imho very poor) samples with these common perversions of Repositories and Services. A lot of what I've arrived at comes from the tenants of CQRS and DDD as well as architecting distributed solutions with one-way messaging (ala NServiceBus).

Comment: I'll try to return to this later in the day and add more info about the command handler dispatcher and the other pieces related to IoC.

Comment: Thanks. That would be appreciated. I'm not seeing how you would actually call the `ChangePasswordCommandHandler`, the way you have it set up.

Comment: Is there any chance you can show me how the commands are dispatched? I've been digging around and am having trouble finding decent examples of this.